# In $3$-dimensional space, if lines $L_1$ and $L_2$ do not intersect, then they must be parallel. True or false?

Tags: geometry

Currently just started learning vectors in 3-dimensional spaces and came across this question.

> If lines $L_1$ and $L_2$ do not intersect, then they must be parallel. True or false?

I think it is false because lines need not be parallel if they do not intersect. Lines that do not intersect and are not parallel are called skew lines. They are only parallel if they are in the same plane. Is my reasoning right?

Comment: True - think about the horizontal line along the x axis and the horizontal line along the y axis through (0, 0, 1).

Comment: This seems to be a question about geometry – not vectors.

Comment: This is just a matter of definition . If definition of parallel is that they don't intersect then it doesn't matter if they are in the same plane or not, the definition is satisfied. If you define the parallel to be distance between the two always remain same then two lines that are overlayed on top of each other should be considered parallel. It is all about what definition (s) are being satisfied.

Comment: @jimjim so it is false?

Comment: What is the definition of parallel ?

Comment: In geometry one of definitions of parallel lines are two lines that do not intersect . If that is the definition of parallel that is being used then yes the lines are parallel as they do not intersect. If definition of parallel is something else then what is it ?

Answer (score 1):

The proposition is false.

Two lines are parallel if their direction vectors are dependent (one of them is a multiple of the other). If $u$ and $v$ are two non-zero vectors in 3-dimensional space, there exist lines with direction vectors $u$ and $v$ that don't intersect. If $L$ is the line passing through $(0,0,0)$ and parallel to $u$ and $L_1, L_2, L_3$ are the lines parallel to $v$ passing respectively through $(1, 0, 0), (0,1,0), (0,0,1)$, then one of the $L_i$s does not intersect $L$.

Comment: What is the definition that is being falsified?

Comment: @jimjim I'm sorry, I don't understand your question. Can you give details?

Comment: What is the definition of parallel that has not been satisfied? OP asked a question without giving the definition of parallel that is being used. The geometry tag implicitly excludes ise of vectors for this question, because of that we need to be explicit about the definition of parallel that is or is not being satisfied.

Comment: @jimjim OP says they started learning vectors in 3-dimensional spaces, so I don't see the point in not using vectors. Two lines are parallel if they have proportional direction vectors.

Comment: In that case your definition of the parallel is what the OP should have included into the question, your answer and reasoning is flawless .

Answer (score 0):

Think of a line on your ceiling, running in an East-West direction, and a line on your floor running North-South.

They don’t intersect, obviously, because they’re at different heights, and they’re certainly not parallel.

So, the proposition is false.